# Allocate char* array with boost::make_shared

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, make-shared

To allocate a char* array I would normally write something like:

```
char* arr = new char[size];
```

How can I achieve the same thing using boost::shared_ptr (or probably boost::shared_array) and boost::make_shared?

My guesses are:

```
1) boost::shared_ptr<char[]> arr = boost::make_shared<char[]>(size);

2) boost::shared_ptr<char> arr = boost::make_shared<char>(size);

3) boost::shared_ptr<char> arr = boost::shared_ptr<char>(new char[size]);
```

The last one looks right but is it guaranteed that upon destruction delete [] arr will be called?

Comment: Your question asks about allocating a "char* array", but what you really want is a char array. Do you really want an array of pointers? (And once you realize that, 3 is clearly wrong. It creates a smart pointer whose type says it's to a `char`, not an array of anything.

Comment: So the correct one is 1) ? I thought that 3 declares a pointer to an array because of new char[size]. In other words I expect it to be a pointer to the first character of the array, which is followed by size-1 chars.

Comment: But what you wanted was a smart pointer to an array, that points to the first character in the array. You didn't want a smart pointer to a character that happens to point to the first character in the array. So the *type* is wrong, even though it points to the right thing.

Comment: Ok so 1) is the correct one? And when the object is destructed delete [] arr will be called not delete arr, right?

Comment: The support is documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared_array.html). It's not guaranteed that `delete[]` will be used specifically (if you think about it, that would be inefficient as you'd need a separate object to hold the returned value), but the objects will be properly destructed and the memory freed.

Comment: Another interesting thing is when shared_array<char> should be preferred to shared_ptr<char[]>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct one is `make_shared<T[]>(n)`.

Bear in mind that **pre-c++20** it's an extension not present in the standard library (although `unique_ptr<T[]>` **is** part of the standard).

Boost's `shared_ptr` will indeed call the correct deleter (naively, 
`delete[]`) for it.

Comment: Correcting sehe's statements slightly, the make_shared<T[]>() specialization was overlooked and omitted from the '11 and '14 standards, but has been added to the '17 standard.

Comment: @jschmerge thanks for the addition. I added the _corrected_ addition to the answer :) (Perhaps the details of when it'll be added aren't official yet)

Answer (score 2):

**Boost shared_ptr and make_shared**

Boost supports array allocation and handling using `shared_ptr` and `make_shared`. According to boost's docs:

> Starting with Boost release 1.53, shared_ptr can be used to hold a pointer to a dynamically allocated array. This is accomplished by using an array type (T[] or T[N]) as the template parameter. There is almost no difference between using an unsized array, T[], and a sized array, T[N]; the latter just enables operator[] to perform a range check on the index.

Just use:

```
shared_ptr<char[]> arr(new char[size]);
-- OR --
shared_ptr<char[]> arr = make_shared<char[]>(size);
```

**Standard library**

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), The standard `shared_ptr`, `make_shared` and `allocate_shared` added support for arrays starting from C++20.